# Why does my custom WP role need edit_posts to edit images?

Tags: custom-post-types, images, user-roles

This may be obvious to someone other than myself. I think I remember reading somewhere that an "image" is indeed a form of "post".

- I have a custom post type called "listing"
- I have a custom WP role of "client"

When I'm logged in as the "client", and I launch the media popup, browse to an image, click "show" to open it up, and then click "edit image", I get a -1. Ie. nothing else displays but "-1".

I can fix this issue by assigning my custom role the capability of "edit_posts". Why is this? As soon as I do this, I'm plagued with another problem, the "client" user role now has access to posts, comments & tools, which I don't want.

Perhaps I haven't set up my custom post type correctly with the capabilities? How can I allow the "client" to edit the images but not have access to posts?

```
      $args = array(
    'label' => 'Listing',
    'description' => '',
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'listing',
    'capabilities' => array(
                    'edit_post' => 'edit_listing',
                    'read_post' => 'read_listing',
                    'delete_post' => 'delete_listing',
                    'edit_posts' => 'edit_listings',
                    'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_listings',
                    'publish_posts' => 'publish_listings',
                    'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_listings',
                    'delete_posts' => 'delete_listings',
                    'delete_private_posts' => 'delete_private_listings',
                    'delete_published_posts' => 'delete_published_listings',
                    'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_listings',
                    'edit_private_posts' => 'edit_private_listings',
                    'edit_published_posts' => 'edit_published_listings',
                ),
    'menu_position' => 5, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'has_archive' => false, 
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'listing'), 
    'query_var' => true,
    'supports' => array('title'),
    'labels' => $labels
  );
```

Comment: Here are the capabilities I'm assigning to my custom wordpress role in case anyone can spot something

`delete_listing`
`delete_listings`
`delete_published_listings`
`edit_listing`
`edit_listings`
`edit_published_listings`
`publish_listing`
`publish_listings`
`read`
`read_listing`
`upload_files`

And I seem to need the following also for editing & deleting the images. Thought these would be remapped to edit_listings and delete_listings

`edit_posts`
`delete_posts`

Comment: I found the following post which I'm currently looking into. Seems to be a larger issue than I thought where edit_posts is required. Looks like there is a general problem when using custom post types + custom roles + taxonomies

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-only-works-when-role-has-edit_posts-capability?replies=24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess: because *images* are *Attachments*, and *Attachments* are a *Post-Type*. Thus, in order to edit an image, which is an attachment, which is a post, requires the `edit_post` capability.

**EDIT**

Don't you have your `capability` mapping array keys/values reversed?

e.g. you have `'edit_posts' => 'edit_listings'`. Shouldn't it instead be `'edit_listings' => 'edit_posts'`?

Comment: In my custom post type setup above I've remapped by edit_posts to edit_listings, and the custom wordpress role has "edit_listings" assigned to it. I thought this was the purpose of remapping them, perhaps I was wrong?

Comment: See edit in updated answer.

Comment: Bennett I reversed them but it didn't seem to have any affect and I still need edit_posts in order to be able to edit the image. Still shows -1 without it. I originally followed Justin Tadlock's "setting up your custom post type" example below where he has the _posts on the left and the remapped capabilities on the right. http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types

Comment: After some time working with custom post types, role and capabilities I believe I understand them a great deal more. You were right, an image is a post, therefore in order for a user to be able to edit an image they uploaded, they need `edit_posts`. For them to delete an image, they need `delete_posts`. Not sure why my `edit_listings` didn't correctly map to `edit_posts` in the first place however.

Answer (score 8):

I know this question is a year old now, but I have just discovered there is in fact a way to achieve this, so posting it here in case it's useful to other people:

```
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'my_user_has_cap', 10, 3 );

function my_user_has_cap( $user_caps, $req_cap, $args ) {

    $post = get_post( $args[2] );

    if ( 'attachment' != $post->post_type )
        return $user_caps;

    if ( 'delete_post' == $args[0] ) {

        if ( $user_caps['delete_others_posts'] )
            return $user_caps;

        if ( !isset( $user_caps['delete_others_listings'] ) or !$user_caps['delete_others_listings'] )
            return $user_caps;

        $user_caps[$req_cap[0]] = true;

    }

    if ( 'edit_post' == $args[0] ) {

        if ( $user_caps['edit_others_posts'] )
            return $user_caps;

        if ( !isset( $user_caps['edit_others_listings'] ) or !$user_caps['edit_others_listings'] )
            return $user_caps;

        $user_caps[$req_cap[0]] = true;

    }

    return $user_caps;

}
```

This is based mainly on [this Codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/user_has_cap).

I'm still getting my head round capabilities filters and it's 2:04am, so my code may well be improveable...

Comment: This worked for me. Just a note, there is an extra ")" in the first line of code. In my case, since I'm using a plugin to show people only their own uploads, all I needed was the if statement to check it this is an attachment.

Comment: glad it's useful for you - i've now removed the extraneous bracket, thanks for spotting that.